# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Spring Application I have configured a hibernate connection and when I try to test it by a main class but it giving me an Error.

My main class,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Patient sac = new Patient();
        sac.setPatient_Id("M2314");
        sac.setPatient_Age(23);
        sac.setPatient_Name("Sac");
        sac.setPatient_Address("SGTY NY");


        System.out.println("load context");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");

        PatientService patientService = (PatientService) context.getBean("patientService");
        patientService.persistPatient(sac);

        context.close();
}
```

And my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />


    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tela.pms" />

   <beans:bean id="patientService" class="com.tela.pms.service.impl.PatientServiceImpl"/>
   <beans:bean id="patientdao" class="com.tela.pms.dao.impl.PatientDAOImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.tela.pms.domain.Patient</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My folder structure :

[image: folder structure]

Exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tela.pms.Test.HibernateTester.main(HibernateTester.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: can you show  web.xml?

Comment: `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");` This path is not correct.

Comment: So what is the correct path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");`

Notice `file:` in front of the path.

Comment: Yes I will, When I tried to accept it, but sof told me to wait for another two minutes. :)